# pointing the website from tomcat to the Apache server

Tags: java, php, apache, web-applications, tomcat

I have a website **website1.com** on Apache server developed using PHP and deployed in Apache Server.

Now I have implemented a new features/modules in Java and JSP technologies and deployed in Tomcat server.
Now what ever I have implemented in Java J2EE techologies should point to the subdomain of actual website website1.com and it should look like  **subdomain1.website1.com**

Both Apache Tomcat and Apache Server resides in the Same machine.

Is that possible? if yes can you please help me how to do that ?

All the environment is set up on LINUX based Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a virtual host with a proxy pass rule. Core of the configuration would be:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

# Default host to handle PHP and static content
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.website1.com
    ServerName www.website1.com
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

# Tomcat redirector
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain1.website1.com
    ServerName subdomain1.website1.com
    # Other directives here
    ProxyPass / ajp://website1.com:8009
</VirtualHost>
```

Assuming you have enabled AJP connecter within your Tomcat configuration and that its running on port 8009.